# Riemann Upper and Lower sums of Heaviside function

Tags: integration, summation, riemann-sum

I've hit a wall with heaviside functions, the question is to find the Riemann sums of, $$\int_{1}^{2}H(x-2)dx$$
and I've worked my way for the partition,
$\Delta x = \frac{1}{n}$, hence $M_{i}=1+\frac{1}{n}$.
Then,
$$U_n=\Delta x \sum_{i=1}^{n} Mi$$
$$U_n=\frac{1}{n} \times \sum_{i=1}^{n} H(-1+\frac{i}{n})$$
How do i go about evaluating this sum?

Comment: Use the definition of $H$.  In particular, $H(x) = 0$ if $x<0$.  That will do everything except the last term.  For that, what is $H(0)$?

Comment: To my knowledge, H(0) is undefined

Comment: If $H(0)$ is undefined, you will need to find out how to do such an integral according to the definition in your textbook.  In fact, we can find $U_n$ in terms of $H(0)$ and show that the limit as $n \to \infty$ is zero regardless of that value is.